# Fabric import bug: "fab task" vs. "from fabfile import task; task()"

Tags: python, encapsulation, fabric, python-import

This also has to do with the Python's import mechanism, and specifically with using `import` inside a function. 
Using Python 2.7.9 and Fabric 1.10.0, create the following three files:

`fabfile.py:`

```
from another import another_hello
def hello():
    print 'hello, world'
    another_hello()
```

`another.py:`

```
def another_hello():
    from secret import TEXT

    print 'Hello, world!'
    print 'text: ' + TEXT
```

`secret/__init__.py:` (also create a folder `secret/`)

```
TEXT = 'secret'
```

Now try `fab hello`. It complains:

```
  File "/home/sergey/projects/Bask/service/t/fabfile.py", line 4, in hello
    another_hello()
  File "/home/sergey/projects/Bask/service/t/another.py", line 2, in another_hello
    from secret import TEXT
ImportError: No module named secret
```

At the same time, you can easily start an interpreter and type
`from fab import hello; hello()`. Works perfectly:

```
In [2]: from fabfile import hello; hello() 
hello, world
Hello, world!
text: secret
```

Why this difference?

Now, I have found a hack that makes this work. Just add an `import secret` to the beginning of `fabfile.py`. I think what happens is that the `fab` tool only works with a proper `PYTHONPATH` when it opens `fabfile.py` to find a particular task, but once it has imported the task and started actually running it, then something changes, so it doesn't have access to the original folder any longer.

Is my hack the way to go? But doesn't it break encapsulation, to say the last, since `fabfile.py` is supposed to know *all indirect dependencies* of any function or method that it invokes? Perhaps it's an argument against `import` statements inside functions?

Comment: I posted answer with link to an issue in Fabric's tracker, but I am not sure if it describes nature of the problem. Let me know if you still need detailed explanation why your import fails

Comment: If I understood correctly, Fabric has a bug whereas it can remove one entry in the module search path for no reason, and this entry often happens to be `''`, thus breaking the imports relative to the current directory.

Comment: yes, `sys.path` is modified by Fabric and thus Python can not find modules in the cwd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known problem in Fabric. There are several issues regarding it in Fabric's issue tracker on Github. See [issue #256](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/256) for example.

**Workarounds**

You can put

```
from secret import TEXT
```

on the first line of `another.py` or add current directory into module search path.

```
def another_hello():

    import sys
    sys.path.insert(0, '')

    from secret import TEXT

    print 'Hello, world!'
    print 'text: ' + TEXT
```